# Running remote batch in elevated command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-services, remote-access

I have a windows service install batch file in a remote computer (`Install.cmd`).
When I run it as administrator, it works just fine.
But when I run a script (`RemoteInstall.cmd`) that run the remote install script, it complete all the steps beside start running.

From my computer -- `RemoteInstall.cmd` script:

```
START /WAIT clusrun /scheduler:RemotePc /nodes:RemotePc /user:Administrator /password:MyPass \\RemotePc\D$\Service\Install.cmd
```

On server -- `Install.cmd` script:

```
%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil MyService.exe
sc config "MyService" start= auto
sc config "MyService" obj= ".\Administrator" password= "MyPass"
sc failure "MyService" actions= restart/10000/restart/10000/restart/10000 reset= 86400
net start MyService
```

The last command returns `errorlevel=2` when I run it from remote, while all the rest return `errorlevel=0` if I run it locally or from remote.
Same error occurs when I use `sc` instead of `net`.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Since you don't show the values of the variables you're using, it's almost impossible to help you...

Comment: thanks. fixed, let me know if it still unclear. I can't write the real names but that's how it written. I added the commands that pass just to have more information.

Comment: What are the Windows version and SP of your local and remote machine(s)? I do not know about `clusrun`, but `PowerShell` has similar capabilities.